# Weblogic deployment exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

When I am deploying an EAR file in weblogic 12.1.1, I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` but strangely deployment is getting successful and I am able to access the application.

But, when the same ear is deployed in our production environment, the below exception is returned and deployment is failed with below error

```
<Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "xyz-scheduler".
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abc.xyz.ModelCI
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:123)
            at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
            at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
            at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
            at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: abc.xyz.ModelCI
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
            at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.
```

The version of weblogic in production is 12.1.2 and I dont have access to view production weblogic settings.

Can anyone help me understand why my deployment is being successful in my local even though it threw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be a consistent behavior. Concentrate in one of your environments and enable the following debug flags to understand how the classloading is working and why it can not find this class:

```
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.ClasspathClassFinder=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.DefaultFilteringClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.FilteringClassLoader.ResourceDump=true 
-Dweblogic.utils.classloaders.URLClassFinder.Verbose=true 
-Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverity=Debug 
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStdoutToServerLogEnabled=true 
-Dweblogic.log.RedirectStderrToServerLogEnabled=true
```

The output will be very verbose. To interpretate it consider the following:

```
Looking for class: CLASSNAME With classpath of (PATH) Classloader object id (CLASSLOADERID)
in case class is not found you will see:
    Class: 'CLASSNAME' not found.**
otherwise:
    Found class: CLASSNAME
```